# npm ERR! missing script: start issue, no typos in my code either

Tags: node.js, docker

I'm not sure what the issue is, i've looked through the files to make sure i didn't make a typo already. Also I've rebuilt and ran the code without retagging it and I still got the same error. Apologies for any issues I posted this.

'''

```
    abdullahyasinahmad@Abdullahs-MBP simpleweb % docker build .                       
    Sending build context to Docker daemon  4.096kB
    Step 1/4 : FROM node:alpine
     ---> 66f36cfbf155
    Step 2/4 : WORKDIR /usr/app COPY ./ ./
     ---> Using cache
     ---> 08a6a62c3c4c
    Step 3/4 : RUN npm install
     ---> Using cache
     ---> def56c80f1c8
    Step 4/4 : CMD ["npm", "start"]
     ---> Using cache
     ---> 7cd4e8bf01d0
    Successfully built 7cd4e8bf01d0

    abdullahyasinahmad@Abdullahs-MBP simpleweb % docker build -t abdullahya/simpleweb .
    Sending build context to Docker daemon  4.096kB
    Step 1/4 : FROM node:alpine
     ---> 66f36cfbf155
    Step 2/4 : WORKDIR /usr/app COPY ./ ./
     ---> Using cache
     ---> 08a6a62c3c4c
    Step 3/4 : RUN npm install
     ---> Using cache
     ---> def56c80f1c8
    Step 4/4 : CMD ["npm", "start"]
     ---> Using cache
     ---> 7cd4e8bf01d0
    Successfully built 7cd4e8bf01d0
    Successfully tagged abdullahya/simpleweb:latest
    abdullahyasinahmad@Abdullahs-MBP simpleweb % docker run abdullahya/simpleweb
    npm ERR! missing script: start
    
    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-11-16T23_36_57_124Z-debug.log
```

'''

## Specify a base image

FROM node:alpine

#Install some dependencies

WORKDIR /usr/app COPY ./ ./

RUN npm install

## Default command

CMD ["npm", "start"]

```
    {

        "dependencies": {
          "express": "*"
        },
        "scripts": {
          "start": "node index.js"
        }
      }

    const express = require("express");


    const app = express();


    app.get("/", (req, res) => {
      res.send("Hi there");
    });

    app.listen(8080, () => {
      console.log("Listening on port 8080");
    });
```

DEBUG LOG:

```
    Nov 16 19:23:33 Abdullahs-MBP com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]                         
    (com.apple.xpc.launchd.domain.pid.docker-credenti.53753): Failed                         
    to bootstrap path: path = /usr/local/bin/docker-credential- 
    osxkeychain, error = 2: No such file or directory

    Nov 16 19:23:33 Abdullahs-MBP com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] 
    (com.apple.xpc.launchd.domain.pid.docker-credenti.53755): Failed 
    to bootstrap path: path = /usr/local/bin/docker-credential- 
     osxkeychain, error = 2: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Could you add the contents of the debug log, referenced in the error message: npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-11-16T23_36_57_124Z-debug.log

Comment: `COPY` needs to be on its own line; as you've shown it (and as it's in the `docker build` output) it's on the same line as `WORKDIR`, so nothing's actually getting copied into the image.

Comment: Make sure you have the start script in your package.json and that you are really coping that using your dockerfile. Try adding COPY package*.json ./ in your dockerfile.